# Как использовать Authenticator при создании Retrofit клиента?

Tags: android, retrofit

Добрый день. Необходимо использовать jwt для аутентификации в приложении. Пришел к выводу что Authenticator подойдет. Но не могу найти годных мануалов по его привязке к Retrofit. Подскажите как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Retrofit для обращения к серверу использует клиент OkHttp. Вам нужно искать `OkHttp Authenticator`.

Например, вот:

- https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes#handling-authentication
- https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/recipes/Authenticate.java
- https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/Authenticator.html