# Подставлять токен в запрос не вручную

Tags: android, get, token

Подскажите каким образом подставлять токен в запрос.Токен я получаю и записываю в переменную. А как дальше в .addHeader его положить не понимаю, конечно если его вручную туда не скопирую). Каким образом сюда прикрутить interceptor

```
public void getHttpResponse() throws IOException {
 String url = "https://сайт.com/api/v1/Lang=1033&dstLang=1049";

 OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
                .build();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .method("GET", null)
                .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "сюда мне нужно класть токен"")
                .build();
 client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                String mMessage = e.getMessage().toString();
                Log.w("failure Response", mMessage);
                //call.cancel();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

                String mMessage = response.body().string();
                Log.e(TAG, mMessage);
                answer.setText(mMessage);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: 'Каким образом сюда прикрутить interceptor' - методом addInterceptor()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для автоматического крепления токена к запросу используются перехватчики или по английски Interceptor. Есть два вида на мой взгляд таких перехватчиков - простой и сложный. Если брать простой, то он называется Authentificator:

```
     class TokenAuthenticator : Authenticator {
    override fun authenticate(route: Route?, response: Response): Request? {
        // This is a synchronous call
        val updatedToken = getUpdatedToken()
        return response.request().newBuilder()
                .header(ApiClient.HEADER_AUTHORIZATION, updatedToken)
                .build()
    }

    private fun getNewToken(): String {
        val requestParams = HashMap<String, String>()
        ...

        val authTokenResponse = ApiClient.userApiService.getAuthenticationToken(requestParams).execute().body()!!

        val newToken = "${authTokenResponse.tokenType} ${authTokenResponse.accessToken}"
        SharedPreferenceUtils.saveString(Constants.PreferenceKeys.USER_ACCESS_TOKEN, newToken)
        return newToken
    }
}
```

В нем вы передаете токен в заголовках к запросу и если что-то происходит не по сценарию, например токен протух, то данный перехватчик пошлет запрос на обновление токена и повторит запрос. Второй вариант - писать свой аналог authentificator при помощи interceptor. У меня был подобный [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1091102/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%B2-interceptor-android-retrofit) некоторое время назад и благодаря [@ЮрийСПБ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/17609/%D0%AE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9%D0%A1%D0%9F%D0%B1) у меня получилось понять как именно и что нужно сделать чтобы решить мою задачу. Ниже привожу пример того что у меня используется в качестве перехватчика:

```
class AuthToken(context: Context) : Interceptor {
    var cont = context
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val sp = cont.getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREFS_STORAGE, 0)
        if (check_expiration) {
            updateAccessToken(cont)
        }

        val initialRequest = if (check_expiration) {
            updateAccessToken(cont)
            requestBuilder(chain)
        } else {
            requestBuilder(chain)
        }


        val initialResponse = chain.proceed(initialRequest)

        return if (initialResponse.code == 401
                && !sp.getString("refresh_token", "").isNullOrBlank()
                && check_expiration) {
            updateAccessToken(cont)
            initialResponse.close()
            val authorizedRequest = initialRequest
                    .newBuilder()
                    .addHeader("Content-type:", "application/json")
                    .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + sp.getString("access_token", "")!!)
                    .build()
            chain.proceed(authorizedRequest)
        } else {
            if (initialResponse.code == 500) {
                val thread = object : Thread() {
                    override fun run() {
                        Looper.prepare()
                        Toast.makeText(cont, cont.getString(R.string.server_error_500), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        Looper.loop()
                    }
                }
                thread.start()
            }
            initialResponse
        }
    }


    private fun updateAccessToken(context: Context) {
        val sp = context.getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREFS_STORAGE, 0)
        synchronized(this) {
            val tokensCall = accessTokenApi()
                    .getNewToken(ReqAccessToken(sp.getString("refresh_token", "")!!))
                    .execute()

            if (tokensCall.isSuccessful) {
                val responseBody = tokensCall.body()
                val editor = sp.edit()

                val localTime = SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(tokensCall.headers()["Date"]!!)
                Singleton.setServerTime(localTime!!.time / 1000, context)

                editor.putString("access_token", Objects.requireNonNull<ResNewTokens>(responseBody).access_token).apply()
                editor.putString("refresh_token", Objects.requireNonNull<ResNewTokens>(responseBody).refresh_token).apply()
                editor.putLong("expires_in", responseBody!!.expires_in!!).apply()
            } else {
                when (tokensCall.code()) {
                    500 -> {
                        val thread = object : Thread() {
                            override fun run() {
                                Looper.prepare()
                                Toast.makeText(cont, cont.getString(R.string.server_error_500), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                                Looper.loop()
                            }
                        }
                        thread.start()
                    }

                    401 -> {
                        Singleton.logOut(context)
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }


    private fun requestBuilder(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Request {
        return chain.request()
                .newBuilder()
                .header("Content-type:", "application/json")
                .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + cont.getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREFS_STORAGE, 0).getString("access_token", "")!!)
                .build()
    }

    private fun accessTokenApi(): APIService {
        val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        interceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY

        val dispatcher = Dispatcher()
        dispatcher.maxRequests = 1


        val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                .connectTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .dispatcher(dispatcher)
                .readTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build()


        client.dispatcher.cancelAll()

        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BuildConfig.API_URL)
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()

        return retrofit.create(APIService::class.java)
    }
}
```

Тут происходит проверка на протухлость токена и если все гуд то шлется запрос. Вот как подключить данный перехватчик к запросу:

```
val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                .addInterceptor(AuthToken(context))
                .connectTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .dispatcher(dispatcher)
                .readTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build()
```

Если же нет желания строить велосипед, то я бы советовал использовать `Authentificator`. Но вам нужно так же кроме его подключения передавать либо токен либо контекст для получения доступа к хранилищу. Вот пример подключения Authentificator:

```
 OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS.toLong(), TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS.toLong(), TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .authenticator(TokenAuthenticator())`
                .addInterceptor(MyInterceptor())
```

[Туториал_1](https://dev.to/mohitrajput987/refresh-authentication-token-in-retrofit-without-modifying-any-call-1ogb),[туториал_2](https://medium.com/knowing-android/headers-interceptors-and-authenticators-with-retrofit-1a00fed0d5eb) [подобный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/622556/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-authenticator-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-retrofit-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0).